# jQuery I want to list only users with postion : 2 from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database

My problem is that I don't know how to list users with position 2. I have one user class and enumeration class called postion and I have three positions (admin, member, coach). And I want to list all users whose position is 2, that is, the coach, via ajax. Does anyone know where to put the if or how I could do it, this is my attempt.

$(document).ready(function () {    // Čeka se trenutak kada je DOM(Document Object Model) učitan da bi JS mogao sa njim da manipuliše.

```
   // ajax poziv za dobavljanje svih zaposlenih sa backend-a i prikaz u tabeli
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",                                                // HTTP metoda
       url: "http://localhost:8080/api/korisnik",                 // URL koji se gađa
       dataType: "json",
       // tip povratne vrednosti
       success: function (data) {                              // ova f-ja se izvršava posle uspešnog zahteva
           // ispisujemo u konzoli povratnu vrednost radi provere
         if(data.position == 2){
            for (let responseElement of data) {
                // prolazimo kroz listu svih zaposlenih
                let row = "<tr>";                                   // kreiramo red za tabelu
                row += "<td>" + responseElement.ime + "</td>";       // ubacujemo podatke jednog zaposlenog u polja
                row += "<td>" + responseElement.prezime + "</td>";
                row += "<td>" + responseElement.email + "</td>";
                row += "<td>" + responseElement.position + "</td>";
                // kreiramo button i definisemo custom data atribut id = id zaposlenog
                let btn = "<button class='btnSeeMore' data-id=" + responseElement.id + ">See More</button>";
                row += "<td>" + btn + "</td>";                      // ubacujemo button u poslednju ćeliju reda
                btn = "<button class='btnDelete' data-id=" + responseElement.id + ">Delete</button>";
                row += "<td>" + btn + "</td>";
                row += "</tr>";                                     // završavamo kreiranje reda

                $('#responseElement').append(row);
                // ubacujemo kreirani red u tabelu čiji je id = employees
            }
        }
           console.log("SUCCESS:\n", data);
       },
       error: function (data) {                                // ova f-ja se izvršava posle neuspešnog zahteva
           console.log("ERROR:\n", data);
       }
   });
```

});

Comment: From the [tag:javascript] tag info: "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: What's not working in your current implementation?

Comment: You've just got your `if` in the wrong place. Remove `if(data.position == 2){`,  then put this: `if (responseElement.position == 2) {`  after this: `for (let responseElement of data) {`

Comment: @charlietfl He throws me nothing out in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the position inside for loop as mentioned below

```
for (let responseElement of data) {
      if( responseElement.position==2){
                    // prolazimo kroz listu svih zaposlenih
                    //your code here
                    
                }
    }
```